Selling Primary Residence Home Owner Exemption
My understanding is that one must use the property as a primary residence for 2 out of the last 5 years (unless their is an exemption, such as a new job). Likewise, my understanding is that the 24 month requirement, need not be continuous and is met, even if one goes on vacation or has short absences. My understanding is that the exemption is defined as a percentage of the last 5 years in which the qualifying time is being met.
Scenario. Owns house 2 years. Puts house on market. Rents apartment while waiting for house to sell. House sells 1 year later. Is the exemption at 66%? Or is the 1 year considered a "short absence"?
I guess my main question is: Is the time spent trying to sell your primary residence considered a "short absence"?
This scenario could be changed in several ways. Such as the person lives there 1yr11m and spends the next month moving into apartment, so they can sell. Do they now no longer qualify? What if they live 1yr10m and move to apartment?
Is it the case then, that anyone that has a vacant house on the market for more than 1 day, or 1 month, or 6 months, NEVER qualifies for a full exemption?
That doesn't sound right, and I have never heard of a realtor or escrow office include this information in their forms, when reporting.
Thoughts?

the amount of gains excluded is same.. you either qualify or you don't...  up to 250,000 or 500,000 methinks based on filing (single/married).   I think same goes for like-kind sell/purchase (rental property for rental property):  https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/like-kindproperty.asp  Which is why some people will rent out their primary residence for 2 years before selling it to buy another.

I think in like-kind the taxes on gains are deferred.  This link explains a bit more:  https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/06/capitalgainhomesale.asp


My understanding is that the exemption is defined as a percentage of the last 5 years in which the qualifying time is being met.

Not exactly. You're talking about the IRC Sec. 121 exemption. The proration is covered in IRC Sec. 121(c), and covers these cases:

(2) Sales and exchanges to which subsection applies
This subsection shall apply to any sale or exchange if—
(A) subsection (a) would not (but for this subsection) apply to such sale or exchange by reason of—
(i) a failure to meet the ownership and use requirements of subsection (a), or
(ii) subsection (b)(3), and
(B) such sale or exchange is by reason of a change in place of employment, health, or, to the extent provided in regulations, unforeseen circumstances.

Another case is non-qualified use (IRC Sec. 121(b)(5)), which also requires proration, in a slightly different manner than the one you mentioned.
So yes, it doesn't sound right - because it's not right. Only specific situations require proration: non-qualified use (IRC Sec. 121(b)(5)) and exceptions from the minimum 2 year qualification or repeated sale period (IRC Sec. 121(c)(2)).

So what happens to the person that lives in the place for 1yr10m gets a new job, moves to another city, puts the place on the market 3 months later, and sells it 5 months later. Is the whole 8 month period considered an "aggregate period of qualified absence due to change of employment, less than 2 years"? If so they qualify for 100%. Or is it the case that they don't get to claim 2 years of primary residency and must do a percentage calculation?

Either outcome is plausible, depending on the specific facts and circumstances of the case. I'd suggest talking to a licensed tax professional (EA or a state-licensed CPA/Attorney specializing in taxes).

What circumstances are you thinking would make each side plausible?

Speculations are off topic. As I said, specific situation requires an advice from a licensed professional. They can help you researching precedents to support your position if that's what you're trying to do.

Sorry. Not trying to ask for speculations. It is simply unclear what details I have left out that would allow for an accurate understanding of the tax code. Thanks for your opinion on the matter.

For example, "temporary absence" assumes an intent to return. So if you're going on a 3 months business trip and return - that is a temporary absence. If you move, and wait for 3 months to list the house just to reach the 2 year mark - that's not a temporary absence. But there may be a lot of gray areas in between - you'll need a qualified professional to evaluate the specifics.
